# Union of two variables to form a new one in Pandas Data Frame - Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a data frame , and I want to create a new data frame based on the values of two columns. The pair of values alwyas would be: `'x' and 'x'` or `'x' and NaN` or `NaN and 'x'` or `NaN and NaN`. So for the first three examples the values of the new varabiel would b `'x'` and for the last one would be `NaN`. Nan is missing value.

The pandas data frame is:

```
Name    Company nameC.antiguo   Company nameC.completado
 ssd         X                           X
 adf         B                          NaN
 dsf         C                           C
 eee         NaN                        NaN
 wqe         NaN                        C
```

I tried the following code but it doen´t work at all.

```
pruebaofempat['bn']= pruebaofempat['Company nameC.antiguo'] + pruebaofempat['Company nameC.completado']
```

So, How Can I create the new variable correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna):

```
>>> df
  Name antiguo completado
0  ssd       X          X
1  adf       B        NaN
2  dsf       C          C
3  eee     NaN        NaN
4  wqe     NaN          C
>>> df['antiguo'].fillna(df['completado'])
0      X
1      B
2      C
3    NaN
4      C
Name: antiguo, dtype: object
```